# REVTeX: Avoid titlepage in single column mode

Tags: titles, revtex

I have a simple document which uses the RevTeX 4.1 documentclass. When I use the twocolumn command in the documentclass, the text in the columns overlap, so I want to use a single column. However, when I remove the twocolumn option, the title gets printed on its own page, and I want to avoid this. Example:

```
\documentclass[amssymb, pra, 10pt, aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathptmx, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\title{Sixth questions of the Putnam competition}
\maketitle
\begin{itemize}\item[1988 -- A6]
If a linear transformation $A$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space has $n+1$ eigenvectors such that any $n$ of them are linearly independent, does it follow that $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity? Prove your answer.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This question is the converse of [Creating title page in revtex with twocolumn layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110033/creating-title-page-in-revtex-with-twocolumn-layout).

Comment: pass the option `notitlepage`?

Comment: That was easier than expected... If you make that an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the `notitlepage` option to the document class.

```
\documentclass[amssymb, notitlepage, pra, 10pt, aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathptmx, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \title{Sixth questions of the Putnam competition}
    \maketitle
    \begin{itemize}\item[1988 -- A6]
        If a linear transformation $A$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space has $n+1$ eigenvectors such that any $n$ of them are linearly independent, does it follow that $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity? Prove your answer.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]